# Why does Yasha feel guilty here in "The Magician of Lublin"?

Tags: yiddish-language, isaac-bashevis-singer, the-magician-of-lublin

When Yasha is sitting on a café in *The Magician of Lublin*, observing the other patrons (generally well-to-do Poles) it's mentioned that he feels a certain sadness or guilt:

> He, Yasha, was to all appearances their equal, yet a barrier separated them. But what was it? He never found a clear explanation. Together with his ambition and lust for life, dwelt a sadness, a sense of the vanity of everything, a guilt that could never be repaid nor forgotten. What was life's purpose if one did not know why one was nor why one died?
> <sub>(translated by Elaine Gottlieb and Joseph Singer, 1960)</sub>

Why does Yasha feel guilty here? Why is it mentioned here in this scene where he's observing the other patrons of the establishment? What is this sadness / guilt?